# MobileIron Access, clarification needed

Tags: mobile

Running Android 6.0

Got a reminder to update Mobile Iron 9.1.0.1. According to description it Mobile Iron has access to SMS, Browsing History etc. This notification directly contradicts with what they [say](https://www.mobileiron.com/en/company/press-room/press-releases/people-don%E2%80%99t-know-what-employers-can-and-cannot-see-their-mobile)

```
The facts: what the employer cannot see:

 - Information in apps – unless the app has been built to transmit
 - information to a corporate server 
 - Personal email and attachments
 - Texts 
 - Photos 
 - Videos 
 - Web browsing activity 
 - Voicemails
```

**And latest updates is asking me to give app access to Photos too? What's going on here? Please help me understand.**

In addition, MobileIron [SPECIFICALLY](https://www.mobileiron.com/en/video/visual-privacy) calls on that Photos, Video etc is not being monitored by MobileIron or Enterprise IT

Very confused here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** My organization uses MobileIron, but I am not my organization's MobileIron administrator.  However I have some experience with other MDM solutions.

I would suspect that MobileIron still needs to monitor for activity in various areas.  Also, it needs to allow for containerization of corporate email, files, photos, etc. separate from personal content.  Just because MobileIron is asking for permission to view and get its fingers in those areas, doesn't mean that the MobileIron administrator will be able to view all the photos on your phone that are not in the container.

Answer (score 1):

Sara Day here from MobileIron Communications.

On Android, the access to Photos / Media / Files is a blanket permission that Google lumps together. This is very confusing to the user, we realize, because MobileIron software does not access photos, media, or web browsing activity on the device. MobileIron software does use the file access permission but only to be able to download and install authorized apps from your IT department and to be able to write and report log files for troubleshooting. On Android, it is also possible for your IT department to collect SMS messages and phone call logs, though usually this is only done in highly regulated industries. This is not possible on iOS.

Note that all data collection policies for MobileIron software are set by your IT department, not MobileIron, so please make sure to confirm your company’s policy with them.

The web page referenced here is specific to iOS, so we have updated it to make that more prominent: https://www.mobileiron.com/en/company/press-room/press-releases/people-don%E2%80%99t-know-what-employers-can-and-cannot-see-their-mobile.